# content description in image button

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android.While designing ai image button in the graphical layout in .xml file ,I'm getting error.
the error if "Missing contentDescription attribute on image "

Now how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add a content description or disable it with

```
android:contentDescription="@null"
```

Comment: Actually you should use...
tools:ignore="ContentDescription"

Make sure you include the namespace in the top like...
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"